# Regular expression to remove link from image in html

Tags: c#, regex, html-agility-pack

What would be the C# / regex syntax to remove the link from the first image in a body of text like:

```
text
<a href="..." class="..."><img src="..." class="..." width="..." /></a>
more text
<a href="..." class="..."><img src="..." class="..." width="..." /></a>
even more text
```

So that the final result would be:

```
text
<img src="..." class="..." width="..." />
more text
<a href="..." class="..."><img src="..." class="..." width="..." /></a>
even more text
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of removing the link I'd rather give you a new one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/93462

Comment: Obligatory- see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/308851

Comment: Obligatory Note: [You can't parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/21567). You might have a special case here, but this is not obvious from the question.

Comment: Oh my, four identical links within a minute. People really got sensitive to that issue ;-)

Comment: Yea, this is simply for a quick piece of throw away code.  It didn't have to be elegant.  Thanks for the posts!

Comment: Kudos for requesting a way to do it with C# and/or regex. As answered below, you can use the HTML Agility Pack with C# to solve this without writing a Regex. You can also solve this using Regex if your data is very consistent and/or you only need to use it once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the HTML Agility Pack ([project page](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), [nuget](http://nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack)), this does the trick:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml("text <a href=\"...\" class=\"...\"><img src=\"...\" class=\"...\" width=\"...\" /></a> more text"
     +" <a href=\"...\" class=\"...\"><img src=\"...\" class=\"...\" width=\"...\" /></a> even more text\"");

var firstImage = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("img").Where(node => node.ParentNode.Name == "a").FirstOrDefault();

if (firstImage != null)
{
    var aNode = firstImage.ParentNode;
    aNode.RemoveChild(firstImage);
    aNode.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(firstImage, aNode);
}

var fixedText = doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
//doc.Save(/* stream */);
```

I personally find this a lot easier on the eyes, as it clearly states what you are trying to accomplish.

1. Find the first IMG inside an A tag
2. Store the IMG temporarily
3. Remove Swap the IMG and the A tag
4. Save the results.

Answer (score 2):

Do yourself a favor and use something like [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).  As we mentioned in the comments, regex and HTML only leads to tears.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
 <a\s[^>]*href\s*=\s*\"([^\"]*)\"[^>]*>(.*?)</a>
```

Comment: Probably due to the fact that it's just a regex without explanation how it works and why it would be a good solution. And also without the warning that using Regex to make changes to HTML is usually a no-no. Especially since there are very easy to use alternative solutions where you could have pointed the OP towards.

Comment: not a good reason , he asked a regex or C# code , I suggested one , I'm not to explain every thing , I give points , he should use them to solve his problem .

Comment: Edited your answer to make it constructive. This solution will help others who stumble upon the same post with a concrete example on how to use it and it provides enough links to external contents to help the reader find a similar solution in the future.